# Refresh browser after modal dialog

Tags: oracle-apex

My application calls a modal window from the navigation bar. The modal window has a pop-up LOV where the user selects an organization they wish to view data for. As soon as the change event occurs, the page is submitted, recording the new organization id and organization name into session state. The modal dialog is then closed.

The navigation bar displays the name of the organization that is stored in session state, making it simple for the user to tell which organization they are working with.

Since the modal to change organizations can be accessed from any page in the application, I need to be able to refresh the web browser to pick up the new organization name displayed in the nav bar once the modal has closed.

I've seen several posts online as to how to refresh a region or report once a modal closes, but I've not uncovered how to refresh the browser window, or perhaps alternatively, how to redirect back to the page where the user was when they accessed the modal via the nav bar.

How can this be achieved?

(Nav Bar displaying current context, and link to modal window)

[image: Nav Bar displaying current context, and link to modal window]

Comment: What you are probably looking for is Branching. In the Processes tab you can add a Branch for after submit that redirects to your original page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@TineO - I was orginally thinking the same as you suggested, but the implementation wasn't coming together for me.

After further internet mining, I found [this blog post](https://jeffkemponoracle.com/?s=APEX_PAGE.GET_URL) which led me to a working solution, below. The bind variable :REFERRING_PAGE is a hidden field, which is populated by the link in the nav bar, using the configuration in the second image below.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create dynamic action or process which can work on 'click' action. You may just run 'submit page' or pl/sql or from a huge list of activities as per your need.
Hope this helps.